# How to export a dictionary to excel using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to export some data from python to excel using Pandas, and not succeeding. The data is a dictionary, where the keys are a tuple of 4 elements.

I am currently using the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel("*file location*", index=False)
```

and I get an exported 2-column table as follows:

[image]

I am trying to get an excel table where the first 3 elements of the key are split into their own columns, and the 4th element of the key (Period in this case) becomes a column name, similar to the example below:

[image]

I have tried using different additions to the above code but I'm a bit new to this, and so nothing is working so far

Comment: Hey Brandon, welcome to SO! You need be aware that this is a community driven site, so you need to make every effort to make your question _reproducible_, meaning that someone can copy your code into their text editor and replicate your problem. (you can't copy images!) Have a read of [mcve] and [ask] and edit your question in kind. Or ask a new question if this one gets closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you show us (which is unreplicable), you need [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

```
df_       = df.set_index(0)  # `0` since your tuples seem to be located at the first column
df_.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_.index)  # We convert your simple index into NDimensional index                 

# `~.unstack` does the job of locating your periods as columns 
df_.unstack(level=-1).droplevel(0, axis=1).to_excel(
    "file location", index=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try exporting to a csv instead

```
df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv', index = False)
```

which can then be converted to an excel file easily